# Float a Div over Google Maps at specific lat / lng

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to build the front end to a web app with a map. I really want to float a div at a specific lat / lng location. I can not do it by pixel as this will not account for screen size changing on different screens.

Has anyone done this before, I think I would need to read the lat long location and see where is in on the screen, then update the css to allow the div to be positioned correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Overlay View.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView

See the Google example here:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

Answer (score -3):

Click anywhere on [**this map**](http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_elevation.html) and a div is placed at the clicked lat/lon